# How to exclude some data for some users?

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I have a main admin with a value of 2 in the users table in the admin column. There are also regular admins with a value of 1, and users with a value of 0.

The main admin has the ability to appoint other users as admins and take admin rights. I have a user list page, I managed to make a SQL query so that none of the regular admins have the main admin displayed. I also want to make sure that the regular admin is not displayed for other regular admins, but is displayed for the main admin. How to do it? Does SQL have exceptions? I read something about EXCLUDE, but I don't know yet if it will help me. Any ideas for an easier way to do this?

```
$ceo = 2;
$sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT id, name, email, admin, position, blocked, deleted FROM workers WHERE email!=? AND admin!=?");
$sql->bind_param("si", $_SESSION['user'], $ceo);
$sql->execute();
$users_listdb = $sql->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

`$ _SESSION['user']` contains the email address of any authorized user.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this query, and what is actually your issue?

Comment: This query displays a list of users, excluding the main admin and the regular admin who is viewing the list. And the problem is described in the main question. Is it possible to modify this request in order to additionally remove other regular admins from the list of admins, but leave the display of absolutely all users for the main admin? I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: Of course, just use a different query for admins and main admin, or as an alternative select all users (no condition on admin column) and filter them out in PHP based on the current user's access level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `if` statements to update the SQL Query based on the user's level.

Assuming the user is logged in and the user's id is an `$id` variable.

```
// User ID's 
$main_admin_id = 2;
$admin_id = 1;
$user_id = 0;

$sql = "SELECT id, name, email, admin, position, blocked, deleted FROM workers WHERE email != ?";
if ($id == 1) $sql .= ' AND (admin = ? OR admin = ?)';
else if ($id == 0) $sql .= ' AND admin = ?';

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

if ($id == 0) $stmt->bind_param('si', $_SESSION['user'], $user_id);
else if ($id == 1) $stmt->bind_param('sii', $_SESSION['user'], $main_admin_id, $admin_id);
else $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user']);

$stmt->execute();
$users_listdb = $sql->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```